# Primefaces 5.0.4 No AtmosphereHandler found

Tags: primefaces, atmosphere

im using Primefaces 5.0.4 with JSF 2.2 and Jboss wildfly. I did set up Atmosphere as follows:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime-native</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-websockets</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when I start my application the following error is thrown:

```
Exception handling request to /test/primepush/notify:     org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler found. Make sure you define it inside WEB-INF/atmosphere.xml or annotate using @___Service
```

According to primefaces showcase and the primefaces user guide you don't have to make any further configuration. Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

regards

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces 5 Push is not working with atmosphere-runtime-native: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7189

In my case, as I'm currently only using web sockets, replacing with the regular atmosphere runtime solved the problem.